# how can I implement infinite scroll with custom queries in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5.3

how can I implement infinite scroll with custom queries in Laravel ?
Something like :

```
$query = Select * from table join table2 on condition where condition order by c1 ;
$l = DB::select($query)->paginate(12);
```

I have 5 fields state, region, city, category and price_range. User can search by any no of fields 1 to 5. Then I have some other url parameters to take care of like sorting.

So if I use custom queries then I can concatenate the received values from url, and running query on one time.

This is scenario, that I have. And final query will look like I posted above.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for your case, you can chain conditions like this:

```
$query = DB::table('table1')
->join('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.table_id');

if ( $request->has('state') && $request->state != '' ) {
    //We have a state in the query and it's not empty
    $query->where('table1.state', '=', $request->state);
}

if ( $request->has('region') && $request->region != '' ) {
    //We have a region in the query and it's not empty
    $query->where('table1.region', '=', $request->region);
}

//We finished checking all our conditions
//Finishing the query now...

$l = $query->paginate(12);
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem with query builder is that I am running a search script and I need some kind of concatenation in query as per condition. Writing query every time based on a condition is not a good idea I guess. And DB::raw() returns an array on that pagination do not work.

Comment: You can try the third option. It lets you run a raw query;

Comment: Yes but it doesn't allow usage of pagination() on it

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Replacing Model with DB don't work, `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::selectRaw()`

Comment: If you can't get it to work, then I suggest method 1. You add your own pagination in SQL by using the `LIMIT` keyword

Comment: You said " I need some kind of concatenation in query as per condition". Can you give an example in the question. I could convert it to use query builder. You can chain condition by saving the query in a variable.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Updated my answer with conditions